# How do I access google maps marker variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have various google maps markers that are created in a loop and are output like below:

```
var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates),map:map,title:'example'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker1,'click',function(){infwind(marker1,'<p>some info</p>')});
```

since it is being declared with "var" doesn't this make it a variable with global scope?

I need to access all the info in the various marker variables for different purposes but I am having trouble getting the info I need.

I am very new to google maps (as in day one)

When I try:

```
console.log(marker1);
```

I get an error that marker1 is not defined. How can I access these markers? I assume I either have to do something like google.maps.someotherstuff or these variables are simply not as global as I think.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, prefacing a variable with `var` in Javascript means that the variable is local in scope to the containing function. All undeclared variables will be considered global.

Answer (score 0):

you could specify the ID when creating the marker, and then reference that ID later on...

creating a marker:

```
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      id: place your id here
    });

markers.push(marker)
```

then you can refernce that id along the lines of:

```
for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  if (marker[i].id == '') {
    do something;
}
}
```